# Late answers with little to no new information

Tags: discussion

When reviewing answers, what should be done with ones like this:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/29693/14401

which are late, and add almost no new information to the question that was not already present from previous answerers?

I don't think we want to discourage new users, but answers like this are also not helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen other reviewers add comments to the effect that the new answer has not added any value. I don't think that it is wrong to point this out. Something along these lines ought to fit the bill,

> The answer you have posted does not provide much information that
>   can't be found in existing answers and might therefore be down-voted.
>   Note that you can edit to improve your answer, and thereby increase
>   the chances of receiving up-votes.

That's not exactly gushy, but it's not unfriendly either.

The answer you gave as an example tells us that the white-seed pomegranates are sweeter than the tarter red-seed varieties. This information isn't present in the first answer and so the poster, in this case, might take umbrage at receiving the comment I suggest above, even though it is true that they have not added much.

In this case, I think the comment should recognise the fact that there is something new and potentially useful, if only a little,

> This answer adds a little new information, but not enough to warrant
>   posting a new answer. Once you gain enough reputation to do so, it
>   would be better to add this information as a comment on an existing
>   answer. Meanwhile you can edit to improve your answer, and thereby
>   increase the chances of receiving up-votes.

Answer (score 1):

Some people flag these as "very low quality" - in fact, the system automatically flags a lot of them that way.

It's your call, but FWIW, we usually do delete them if they literally add *zero* new information. Or at least I do.

Note, it is OK for a late answer to *consolidate* multiple previous answers into one, as a sort of summary - assuming all those previous answers address different issues and some effort goes into consolidation (i.e. if it's not just a copy/paste job). Obviously that does not apply to this particular example, but just want to let people know that it is an exception to the "rule".